# Travel from Thailand to India by boat/ferry/cargo ship

Tags: india, thailand, ferries, sea-travel

I am trying to travel from Thailand/Malaysia to India by sea. From my research, there is a ship service that takes you from Andaman Islands (Port Blair) to Chennai/Kolkatta by Andaman Tourism India - however, I can’t seem to find any information on any boat/ferry services that takes you from Thailand to Andaman Islands. Does anyone know any private boat service for this route?

I have sent out some emails to some freighter companies and shipping companies and awaiting their replies.

In the meantime, looking for more information here from anyone who has done this route before.

Comment: I took a passenger ship from Madras (it's an old story) to Penang long ago.  Not Thailand but you can then take a train.  Only a comment since I have no idea whether the service is still running.

Comment: thanks for this info! Do u by any chance remember what was the freighter company that u took?

Comment: It was 1983 so unlikely to be the same.  It was not a freighter, it was a scheduled passenger service.  Like a cruise if you had a first class ticket but I had a third class ticket which was cheap but not luxury.

Comment: This might be the ship that I took.  Two years after my trip, it caught fire and at least 27 people died.  It was then scrapped.  So, you are 38 years too late to experience 6 days in a 3rd class cabin as I did.  https://wrecksite.eu/wreck.aspx?284121

Answer (score 2):

I visited the Andamans some time ago and looked into this. As far as I am aware, there are **no direct connections of any kind between the Andamans and Thailand**, not even by airplane.

This is kind of absurd since Thailand is actually closer to the islands than mainland India, but at the end of day it's geopolitics (different country) and economics (the islands are quite small and poor by world standards, and demand for international travel to them is low).

Comment: yeah exactly! I’m on a mission to travel by land/sea from my home country (Singapore) all the way to the US but currently stuck in Thailand/Laos due to political/covid issues in Myanmar/China. Most freighter/shipping companies got back to me saying that they have suspended operations up to 2024, earliest would be 2nd half of 2023 but time is not exactly on my side. I believe there are direct routes to India from Singapore/Malaysia (Port Klang)/Phuket based on https://www.cruisecompete.com/usersuggestedsailings.php/?itinid=15641783&saildate=2023-03-03 so I’m betting on these travel agents

Comment: My ship from Madras to Penang was part of a similar plan: to get from the UK to Australia without using a plane.  I failed, I could not manage the last step to Australia.

Comment: Aw damn but I’m sure it was a crazy journey nonetheless! I think personally my main obstacle is time and I can’t wait until 2024 for normal freighter operations to resume to expand my options of sea travel. I know of this guy who travelled to almost every country (201/203) w/o flying (@onceuponasaga on instagram) and it took him almost 10 years (inclusive a few years of delay due to covid - he was stuck somewhere). I guess being stuck in some country is normal for our kinda journey haha!